# How to send/receive via UDP with ESP8266-12E

Tags: c++, arduino, udp, esp8266

Well I've already done UDP send/receive many times. But now I'm stucked.

Maybe I'm missing some dumb mistake that's in the code or maybe there's problem in the libraries that I'm using. Anyway if there's someone who could help please take a look.

Code of the receiver

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char* ssid = "M3-L7";
const char* password = "mySmartChoice";
unsigned int localPort = 2390; 
char packetBuffer[255];
WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);
  if (Udp.parsePacket()) {
    int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 255);
    if (len > 0) {
      packetBuffer[len] = 0;
      Serial.println(packetBuffer); 
    }
  }
}
```

The code of the sender/accesss point

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char *ssid = "M3-L7";
const char *password = "mySmartChoice";
unsigned int localPort = 2390; 

WiFiUDP Udp;
void setup() {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {
 Udp.beginPacket("192.168.4.1", localPort);
 Udp.write("Hello");
 Udp.endPacket();
 delay(10);
}
```

Well I'd expect "Hello" to be printed repeatedly :D.. they reach the point where they connect but that's over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try adding the following to your receiver just before `Wifi.begin`:

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
```

This sets the Wifi up as a station (client) rather than an access point. Your code isn't doing this so it's difficult to be certain what is going on, especially if you are re-using a device that was previously programmed to run in AP mode.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't ever think about it on my own, it works :D

Comment: No problem. Had a few funnies of my own in the past before I realised I needed to do this!